# I keep trying this code but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, compiler-errors, pycharm

I've been trying this code and I can't seem to get pass this error:

```
" Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\game.py", line 38, in <module>

    play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game=True)

  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\game.py", line 16, in play

    if game.make_move(square, letter):

  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\ttt.py", line 28, in make_move

    if self.board[square] == " ":

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict "
```

Does this have anything to do with my IDE. I'm using `PyCharm` for Windows and the person I'm learning from was using Visual Studio Code for Linux. Below is the code

This is the ttt.py file

```
import math

import random

class Player:

    def __init__(self, letter):  # letter is x or o

        self.letter = letter

    def get_move(self, game):

        pass

class RandomComputerPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):

        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):

        square = random.choice(game.available_moves())

        return square

class HumanPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):

        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):

        valid_square = False

        val = None

        while not valid_square:

            square = input(self.letter + "\'s turn. Input move (0-8): ")

            try:

                val = int(square)

                if val not in game.available_moves():

                    raise ValueError

                valid_square = True

            except ValueError:

                print("Invalid square. Try again. ")

        return val

class GeniusComputerPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):

        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):

        if len(game.available_moves()) == 9:

            square = random.choice(game.available_moves())

        else:

            square = self.minimax(game, self.letter["position"])

        return square

    def minimax(self, state, player):

        max_player = self.letter  # that you aka yourself

        other_player = "0" if player == "X" else "X"

        if state.current_winner == other_player:

            return {"position": None,

                    "Score": 1 * (state.num_empty_square() + 1) if other_player == max_player else -1 * (state.num_empty_square() + 1)}

        elif not state.empty_squares():

            return {"position": None, "Score": 0}

        if player == max_player:

            best = {"position": None, "Score": -math.inf}

        else:

            best = {"position": None, "Score": -math.inf}

        for possible_move in state.available_moves():

            # step1: make a move, try that spot

            state.make_move(possible_move, player)

            # step2: recurse using minimax to simulate a game after making that move

            sim_score = self.minimax(state, other_player)

            # step3: undo the move

            state.board[possible_move] = " "

            state.current_winner = None

            sim_score["position"] = possible_move

            # step4: update the dictionaries if necessary

            if player == max_player:

                if sim_score["score"] > best["score"]:

                    best = sim_score

            else:

                if sim_score["score"] < best["score"]:

                    best = sim_score

        return best
```

And this game.py file

```
import time

from random import random

from ttt import HumanPlayer, RandomComputerPlayer, GeniusComputerPlayer

class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):

        self.board = [' ' for _ in range(9)]  # we will use a single list to represent a 3x3 board

        self.current_winner = None  # keep track of the winner

    def print_board(self):

        for row in [self.board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:

            print("| " + " | ".join(row) + " |")

    @staticmethod

    def print_board_nums():

        number_board = [[str(i) for i in range(j*3, (j+1)*3)] for j in range(3)]

        for row in number_board:

            print("| " + " | ".join(row) + " |")

    def available_moves(self):

        return [i for i, spot in enumerate(self.board) if spot == " "]

    def empty_square(self):

        return " " in self.board

    def num_empty_square(self):

        return self.board.count(" ")

    def make_move(self, square, letter):

        if self.board[square] == " ":

            self.board[square] = letter

            self.current_winner = self.winner(square, letter)

            return True

        return False

    def winner(self, square, letter):

        row_ind = square // 3

        row = self.board[row_ind*3:(row_ind + 1)*3]

        if all([spot == letter for spot in row]):

            return True

        col_ind = square % 3

        column = [self.board[col_ind+i*3] for i in range(3)]

        if all([spot == letter for spot in column]):

            return True

        if square % 2 == 0:

            diagonal1 = [self.board[i] for i in [0, 4, 8]]  # left to right diagonal

            if all([spot == letter for spot in diagonal1]):

                return True

            diagonal2 = [self.board[i] for i in [2, 4, 6]]  # right to left diagonal

            if all([spot == letter for spot in diagonal2]):

                return True

        return False

def play(game, x_player, o_player, print_game=True):

    if print_game:

        game.print_board_nums()

    letter = "X"  # starting letter

    while game.empty_square():

        if letter == "O":

            square = o_player.get_move(game)

        else:

            square = x_player.get_move(game)

        if game.make_move(square, letter):

            if print_game:

                print(letter + f" makes the move to square {square}")

                game.print_board()

                print(" ")

            if game.current_winner:

                if print_game:

                    print(letter + " Wins!!!")

                return letter

            letter = "O" if letter == "X" else "X"

        time.sleep(0.8)

    if print_game:

        print("It's a tie!")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    class HumanPlayer:

        def __init__(self, letter):

            self.letter = letter

        def get_move(self, game):

            while True:

                move = input("Enter your move (0-8): ")

                if move.isdigit():

                    move = int(move)

                    if move in game.available_moves():

                        return move

                print("Invalid move. Try again.")

    class RandomComputerPlayer:

        def __init__(self, letter):

            self.letter = letter

            def get_move(self, game):

                available_moves = game.available_moves()

                return random.choice(available_moves)

x_player = HumanPlayer("X")

o_player = GeniusComputerPlayer("O")

t = TicTacToe()

play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game=True) 

I've tried using this code:

def make_move(self, square, letter):

  square_index = int(square)

  if self.board[square_index] == " ":

    self.board[square_index] = letter
```

I thought it because I int in dict

Comment: `square` is a dictionary, and it's expecting integers or slices. Try printing `repr(square)` to see what you're actually using to index. Most likely the dictionary is returned from the `minimax` function, where you're returning the dictionary `best`.